# Dynamically subset a data.frame by a list of rules

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to subset a `data.frame` by a list of rules dynamically. For example, rules like these ones:

- `df[col1] == 's'`
- `df[col2] == 'z'`
- `df[col3] == 'a' | df[col3] == 'b' | df[col3] == 'c'`

Statically, I would just:

```
df <- df[df[col1] == 's' 
         & df[col2] == 'z' 
         & (df[col3] == 'a' | df[col3] == 'b' | df[col3] == 'c'), ]
```

How could I achieve the same dinamically in case I have a `list` that stores all the rules:

```
rules <- list(col1 = c('s'), col2 = c('z'), col3 = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

I would like to do just this:

```
df <- magic(df, rules)
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very generalized--I mean each element will be `and`s and each of those elements in each element will be `or`s, but that's what your question asks.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('a','s','x'),
                 col2 = c('a','z','s'),
                 col3 = c('a','c','b'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[with(df, col1 == 's' 
         & col2 == 'z' 
         & (col3 == 'a' | col3 == 'b' | col3 == 'c')), ]

#   col1 col2 col3
# 2    s    z    c


rules <- list(col1 = c('s'), col2 = c('z'), col3 = c('a', 'b', 'c'))


df[Reduce(`&`, Map(`%in%`, df, rules)), ]

#   col1 col2 col3
# 2    s    z    c
```

`magic`

```
magic <- function(data, rules) {
  data[Reduce(`&`, Map(`%in%`, data, rules)), ]
}

magic(df, rules)
#   col1 col2 col3
# 2    s    z    c
```

Edit -- version 2

This one should work for 1) columns without rules and/or 2) rules not in the exact order of columns

```
magic <- function(data, rules) {
  rules <- rules[names(data)]
  idx <- Map(`%in%`, data, rules)
  idx[is.na(names(rules))] <- list(rep(TRUE, nrow(data)))
  data[Reduce(`&`, idx), ]
}

df <- data.frame(col1 = c('a','s','x'),
                 col2 = c('a','z','s'),
                 colx = rnorm(3),
                 col3 = c('a','c','b'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


rules <- list(col2 = c('z'), col1 = c('s'), col3 = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
magic(df, rules)
#   col1 col2      colx col3
# 2    s    z -1.374339    c
```

more tests

```
magic(mtcars, list(gear = 4, carb = 1:2))

#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: Dude... that's... that's... AMAZING! Now I will have to understand it, but it's EXACTLY what I need. Thank you very much, to me, you are definitely a R guru!!!

Comment: @thelawnmowerman see edits, I think this one is a little more robust. and thank you for asking an interesting question !

Comment: Definitely, even better!